# Facebook PHP API not always returning event venue data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 3 events:

https://www.facebook.com/491594114271958 (Mad Haus)

https://www.facebook.com/569226999799343 (Deuglish)

539504962802119/ (Piffle)

All are being fetched via the PHP

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = $appId;
$config['secret'] = $secret;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$ev = $facebook->api('/'.$id."?fields=cover,description,location,name,owner,venue",'GET');
print_r($ev);
```

For some reason Mad Haus and Piffle do not return venue data but Deuglish does. All events return basic data such as title, description and start time. When I run them through the Graph API explorer the venue data is returned as expected but not through the PHP API, any ideas? I can not for the life of me see the difference with these 3 events.

Thanks,

Caroline

Comment: I don't think facebook is the problem here, show us more code.

Comment: There you go, thats it. The code otherwise works fine as most of the event data is returned most of the time.

Comment: You apparently should need an access token to query events https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ so that's a really weird bug

Comment: I tried it with and without an access token and it has the same results.

Comment: Well I've tried several things but I got the same problem on my end. Might be worth posting it on facebook bug tracker it definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: Facebook doesn't require venue information to create an event so this field is not always present.

Comment: In the cases of these events the venue information is there

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to wait for the Facebook developers to fix the bug, you can try the same by making a simple GET request (of course along with an Access Token) to Graph API using [PHP cURL](http://codular.com/curl-with-php). Since you are able to retrieve the venues while using the Graph API explorer, I'm pretty sure you'll be able to get them by making a simple GET request using PHP cURL.

This however involves an overhead of parsing the received JSON object and dealing with errors will be a little difficult here. But you can give it a shot.